# Prove the following recurrence: $F_{2n+1}=3F_{2n-1}-F_{2n-3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Prove the following identity:

$$F_{2n+1}=3F_{2n-1}-F_{2n-3}$$

So far I know that $F_n=F_{n-1}-F_{n-2}\implies F_{2n+1}=F_{2n}+F_{2n-1}$

Just not sure where to go from here to get to the conclusion.

Note: $F_i$ is the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ term of the Fibonacci sequence with $F_0=0, F_1=F_2=1$.

Comment: What is the difference between Fibonacci numbers two indices apart from each other? And 3x=2x+x

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: What is F2n-1-F2n-3?

Comment: Isn't it f8 and f9??

Answer (score 2):

Given that the sequence $\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a characteristic polynomial $p(x)=x^2-x-1$ with roots $\phi,\bar{\phi}$, then both the sequences $\{F_{2n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{F_{2n+1}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ have a characteristic polynomial with roots $\phi^2=1+\phi,\bar{\phi}^2=1+\bar\phi$, hence the characteristic polynomial of $\{F_{2n+1}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is $p(x-1)=x^2-3x+1$ from which it follows that:

$$ F_{2n+5} = 3 F_{2n+3}-F_{2n+1}. \tag{1}$$
It is sufficient to check that $(1)$ holds for $n=0,1$ in order that it holds for every $n$ by induction.

If you're still unsatisfied, notice that $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$ F_{2n+4} = 2 F_{2n+3}-F_{2n+1} = F_{2n+3} + F_{2n+2} \tag{2}$$
that is pretty straightforward.

Comment: We can't use induction

Comment: @user226639: it is not needed. My last line is just a double-check of $(1)$. My first lines, or the explicit formula for Fibonacci numbers, are just enough.

Comment: @user226639: moreover, what does it mean "we cannot use induction"? Was it forbidden by some law? "You have to prove this statement with both hands tied to your back"?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to say. No the question can be used with induction but it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, maybe the teacher who gave this to him as homework hasn't allowed him to use induction. :P

Comment: @user226639, no offense though. I was just kidding. :D

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: as a teacher, I don't believe it is a good practice to give homeworks and force someone to solve them without using some perfectly valid and useful mathematical techniques. Anyway, I have just added another proof. I hope that three of them are enough.

Comment: Yea that makes more sense thanks

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I was thinking of another proof that uses the closed form of $F_n$ which is $F_n=\dfrac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$ but I think that'd be too messy.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: the key of my first proof is just that $$ F_{2n+1} = A \phi^{2n}- B\phi^{2n} $$ for some constants $A,B$. With the explicit formula, we just need to prove that $\phi^4 = 3\phi^2-1$ or $F_4=3F_2-F_0$, it is not messy at all.

Answer (score 2):

Using the recurrence $F_{k+1} = F_k + F_{k-1}$ twice we find

\begin{align}F_{2n+1} &= F_{2n} + F_{2n-1} \\
&\underset{(1)}{=} F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-2} + F_{2n-1}\\
&= 2F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-2}\\
&\underset{(2)}{=} 2F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-1} - F_{2n-3}\\
&= 3F_{2n-1} - F_{2n-3}.
\end{align}

The recurrence was used in $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you that make a lot of sense :)